# How to compare Word Documents (Unknown relation)

Tags: comparison, beyondcompare

How do I compare two word documents that are related, but I do not know exactly how.
(Different filenames, different filesizes)

Everything I can find about comparing seems to be abut different version.

Comment: Maybe look for similarities instead of differences? For example [WCopyfind](http://plagiarism.bloomfieldmedia.com/z-wordpress/software/wcopyfind/) -- WCopyfind is an open source windows-based program that compares documents and reports similarities in their words and phrases. It is free and available to anyone. It is licensed under the Gnu Public License

Comment: See also [Comparing Two Versions of a Word Document](http://www.codejacked.com/comparing-two-versions-of-a-word-document/) which gives three different ways. Two do not involve word itself so the files don't have to be different version of the **same** file.

Comment: The link is from 2007 (Also I am hoping for something a bit more straight forward than comparing text versions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare using MS Word.

1. Open the documents that you want to compare.
2. On the Review tab, in the Compare group, click Compare.

See also:
http://support.office.microsoft.com/client/compare-documents-with-the-legal-blackline-option-dbfc7351-4022-43a2-a0c4-54d1898702a0?NS=WINWORD&Version=14

If you have BeyondCompare 3 installed, also does a good job comparing Word documents.
Select the 2 documents, right click, click "compare".
It will compare text only (ignore images, changes in table structures, etc...)

Comment: Can you check the link please? I get an error attempting to open it ...

Comment: @dude - Works for me.  Of course it doesn't change the fact the answer should contain the relevant information instead of just linking to it.

Answer (score 0):

`Beyond Compare 4` does support comparison of Microsoft Word documents. Documents are automatically converted to text form and then compared. You can see it in [feature list](http://www.scootersoftware.com/features.php?zz=features_list):

> Microsoft Word, Adobe PDF, and Rich Text converted to text automatically

This [support page](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_docxlspdf) contains more information:

> ### BC VERSION 3 AND 4
>
> By default, Beyond Compare 3 and 4 support a read-only comparison of Word, Excel, and PDF files.
>
> #### Text Compare
>
> Microsoft Word and Adobe PDF files are converted to plain text and compared in a Text Compare session.  Formatting and embedded images are ignored.
>
> #### Table (Data) Compare
>
> Microsoft Excel files are converted using the copy of Excel on your machine, and then the current sheet is compared in a Table Compare session.  The first column is selected as the default Key, but this is configurable in the session's settings.

You may also install additional [file formats](http://www.scootersoftware.com/download.php?zz=moreformats&version=4&platform=Windows):

```
Microsoft Word documents extended
Microsoft Word documents VBA
```